# simpler way to calculate the minute of the day in bash

Tags: bash, date

I want to know the minute of the day in a bash shell script, and at the moment I can only think to do this by piping two `date` commands with the `hour of day` and `minute of hour` to `bc` in this way:

```
mod=$(echo 60*$(date +%H)+$(date +%M) | bc)

echo $mod
```

This works, but is very clunky and not very elegant, is there a nicer way?  I didn't see an option of minute of day in the date command.

I'm using bash version

```
 4.4.20(1)-release
```

Comment: Which version of bash? (Current releases have a date-formatting tool built into `printf`, so you don't need `date` at all)

Comment: fwiw you can also do math with `$((  ))`, avoiding `bc`!

Comment: sorry, forgot to add, now edited the question to add. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a *more efficient* approach (with bash 4.4 or later), albeit not necessarily a shorter one:

```
printf -v dateMath '%( (10#%H*60)+10#%M )T' -1
mod=$(( dateMath ))
```

...as a less-efficient one-liner (but still much faster than using `date` and `bc`), you could also write this as:

```
mod=$(( $(printf '%( (10#%H*60)+10#%M )T' -1) ))
```

Comment: another advantage of this solution is that on a mac the options for date are different unless you explicitly switch to using gnu date. So this is more cross-platform too. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to measure the efficiency of both solutions ?

Comment: @Philippe, easiest way is a loop inside `time` (the shell-builtin `time`, not the external-command version). As in: `time { for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do printf -v dateMath '%( (%H*60)+%M )T' -1; mod=$(( dateMath )); done; }`, and likewise for the other approaches.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks ! There is a minor issue when %H or %M is 08 (or 09).

Comment: Ooh! Quite right, thank you for calling that out; I'll see about correcting it later in the morning.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins, see the update prepending `10#` to the values emitted by `date` to force base-10 interpretation even when the number includes a leading `0`, which otherwise specifies octal. (Many thanks to Philippe for pointing out the bug).